# What is Visual Studio Code? Is it an efficient tool for Swift Development?

Tags: swift, ide

Scrolling to the #Linkedin feeds I have come across the term #VSCode. Please, anybody, explain the pure purpose of the tool or it's really trending in development

> Visual Studio Code combines the simplicity of a source code editor with powerful developer tooling, like IntelliSense code completion and debugging.

I have a doubt it's a **code once and export to multiple platforms** like a tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is a multi-language IDE and text editor, much like [Atom](https://atom.io/).

Among it's strenghts there's it being highly modular, with plenty of plug-ins so you can build the best IDE for your specific needs.

It has gained quite a lot of traction within the StackExchange community, based on [the latest survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#development-environments-and-tools).

While it's true that [there are plenty of Swift plugins](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=swift&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) for VSCode, I have never used it for this purpose so far, although I enjoy working on it on other languages and as my generally go-to text editor.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing it's a code once and export to multiple platforms like a tool?
Like: Unity3D Developed applications for mobile, desktop, the web, and consoles you need to code once :)

Comment: No, it's not like Unity. Unity is both an IDE, and a game engine built as a framework on top of C#/++, which allows that 'code once, export several' functionality. VSCode is language agnostic, a notepad on steroids (many and very powerful steroids, that is).